# Redirection of single pages to another page - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, opencart, http-status-code-301

I tried different redirects from one page to another (page moved to another url) but nothing is really working - I keep getting 404 page.

I would like to move http://www.staskka.com/mladinska-postelja-gasilec.html to http://www.staskka.com/otroska-oprema/otroske-posteljice/mladinska-otro%C5%A1ka-postelja-gasilec.html

Nothing happens. Still 404 page not found.

Code in .htaccess was:

```
# BEGIN Permanent URL redirects

RewriteRule ^mladinska-postelja-gasilec\.html$ /pohistvo/otroske-posteljice/mladinska-otroška-postelja-gasilec/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

I also have redirection from non www to www.. and works fine..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I only need to redirect some of the URL's because I put them in category and a lot of this sites are ranked on google very well-- Could anybody help me out, please?

Your help is much appreciated .. thanks.

Oh, and I use OC 1.5.1.3.

EDIT: This is the whole .htaccess

```
    rewriteengine on


rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.djecje-kuhinje.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^djecje-kuhinje.com$
rewriterule ^djecje-kuhinje-com\/ "http\:\/\/shop\.djecje-kucice\.com\/" [R=301,L] #52b5421b82424
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.otroska-kuhinja.si$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otroska-kuhinja.si$
rewriterule ^otroska-kuhinja\/ "http\:\/\/www\.otroskekuhinje\.si\/" [R=301,L] #51f13a48f336e
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kidkraft.staskka.com$
rewriterule ^kidkraft\/ "http\:\/\/www\.staskka\.com\/" [R=301,L] #50f3d3a25618d



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]




##BEGIN MOBILE (do not edit below this line)
RewriteBase /
##END MOBILE
rewriterule test\.htm http://www.google.com [R]
rewritecond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ((.*iPhone.*)|(.*iPod.*)|(.*BlackBerry.*)|(.*Android.*Mobile.*)|(.*Windows\ CE.*)|(.*IEMobile.*)|(.*Opera\ Mini.*)|(.*Opera\ Mobi.*))
rewritecond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !dm_show_classic
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} !no_redirect=true [NC]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9a-z-]+\.[a-z]+$ [NC]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_dm/s/ [NC,OR]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|txt|ico|pdf|bmp|tif|mp3|wav|wma|asf|mp4|flv|mpg|avi|csv|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|zip|rar|tar|gz|dmg|iso)$ [NC]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.staskka.com/ [R,L]
rewriterule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
rewriterule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
rewriterule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
rewriterule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]


# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>

mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*

</ifModule>




# BEGIN Permanent URL redirects
RewriteRule ^mladinska-postelja-gasilec\.html$ /pohistvo/otroske-posteljice/mladinska-otroška-postelja-gasilec/? [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question?

Comment: If you are using Opencart, custom redirect rules need to be added at the bottom after all other redirect rules otherwise you might get these specific errors. So posting complete redirect block could help sorting this out.

Comment: Yes, of course.. I can't add code in the comment .. I will add it in the question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i notice in the code the problem lies here:

```
rewriterule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

since having a L flag, it means that after url call the server processes it and ends there, meaning that whatever you write after that if the url is caught in the conditions above will stop there.

So in your specific case you need to add (notice thesame without L Flag as you need Opencart to process it afterwards):

```
RewriteRule ^mladinska-postelja-gasilec\.html$ /pohistvo/otroske-posteljice/mladinska-otroška-postelja-gasilec/? [R=301,NC]
```

after this line

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

let me clarify that i am not certain if the code you use is the one that matches the behavior you want it to. But the position is the correct one. Also since in my comment i stated that you need to add these rules at the end, this is for handling external domains mostly, for your case (internal url handling) this the way to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you Jonid. It helped a little bit, but as you said, not to the right position. It redirects me to the category, but the uRL in browser doesn't change - it stays the same: http://www.staskka.com/mladinska-postelja-gasilec.html

Comment: hmm try it with L Flag : RewriteRule ^mladinska-postelja-gasilec\.html$ /pohistvo/otroske-posteljice/mladinska-otroška-postelja-gasilec/? [L,R=301,NC]  , thinking this again L flag is required becausethe behaviour you are seeing now meens that the redirect is there for the server but since further processing is allowed the server recognizes it. Try with the L Flag like yo previously had ti and tell me the results.

Comment: @ideep13 please review my comment and tell me the results.

Comment: Well URL changed to http://www.staskka.com/pohistvo/otroske-posteljice/mladinska-otro%C5%A1ka-postelja-gasilec.html but I still see the category

Comment: @ideep13 glad i could help :), If you feel the answer deserves to, then accept it :)